# Make a global array for each user in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, global-variables, global

I have an issue and I'm trying to figure out the best/simplest way to resolve this...

I have multiple users on my app. the app allows users to add books to a read-queue list (like a list of books a user can keep tabs on).

Originally, I set the read-queue list as a global array. However this meant that multiple users were adding books to a single global array. If user1 added 3 books, user2 would also see those 3 books. Or if user1 cleared the read-queue list, user2's books were cleared too.

Possible Solutions:

1. Maybe I can create a key in the array to associate a portion of it to a user, but I imagine that the array would get pretty large...
2. Maybe create a db table "queue-list".. but that seems like a lot to do for something like this..
3. **Maybe create a global array unique for each user. (I like this one, but not sure how to do that)**

Hope this is clear, I'm pretty new to rails so any help is appreciated!

my attempt at solution 3:

books_controller.rb

```
def add_book_to_queue
  user = User.find(params[:id])
  user.read_queuelist.push(params[:book_info])
  @readlist = user.read_queuelist
end
```

---

user.rb

```
def read_queuelist
  $read_queuelist ||= Array.new
end
```

---

view

```
<%= @readlist %>
```

---

Answer (score 0):

If your app is simple enough, you could make an array for each user as it's shown below. But if your application is meant to handle a lot of users and tons of books, you should look towards DB integration.

```
class Book
  attrr_accessor :title, :author

  def initialize(t, a)
    @title, @author = t, a
  end
end

class User
  attr_accessor :books

  def initialize
    @books =  Array.new
  end

  def add(b)
    @books << b
  end
end

joe = User.new

joe.add(Book.new("moo", "foo"))

puts "Joe likes #{joe.books.length} books"
```

**UPD:** for rails, take a look at `has_many` and `belongs_to` [associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

Comment: hmm thanks for your response~ I think this is the best solution, ill try it out

Comment: Note: this is the best solution if your application is **simple**. If you are aiming for a business one you **must** be sure it would not fail. In that case you should use database.

Comment: a few hundreds, maybe few thousands or even millions. depends on how complicated your classes are =)

Comment: I tried using this solution for a global array, but it still adds books to a single array. I've updated my question to post my code..

Answer (score 0):

You can create lots of global hashes with Redis. It has the advantage of scaling and being optionally persistant (via backups). See http://redis.io/commands#hash and http://redistogo.com/ for free Redis hosting.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're new to Rails, I think you'll find that using ActiveRecord to persist your model data to a database ends up being the simplest solution.